# ArrayList not expanding when adding objects through a loop

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

I think there might be multiple things wrong but basically I want to add a Ship every time the loop runs through again in my diver class. But for some reason my toString method only outputs the latest one added or the last iteration of the do while loop. I can post all the code if necessary but I assume the problem is in one of these two classes.

**Ship Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ShipDriver 
{


static Ship cS;
static Ship cargo;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("----------------------Ship Company----------------------");
    String name, ans;
    int year, passenger = 0, ton = 0, oneTwo; 
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    ShipCompany sh = new ShipCompany();

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the ship's name:");
        name = kb.next();

        System.out.println("Enter the " + name + " build year:");
        year = kb.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Enter 1 for cruise ship or 2 for a cargo ship");
        oneTwo = kb.nextInt();



        if(oneTwo == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of passengers for the " + name);
            passenger = kb.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the maximum capacity of the " + name);
            ton = kb.nextInt();
        }


        cS = new CruiseShip(name, year, passenger);
        cargo = new CargoShip(name, year, ton);
        sh.add(getInfo(oneTwo));
        System.out.println("Do you want enter another ship's information? y/n");
        ans = kb.next();

    }while(ans.equals("y") || ans.equals("Y") || ans.equals("Yes") || ans.equals("yes") );

    System.out.println(sh.toString());
    kb.close();
}
public static Ship getInfo(int num)
{
    if(num == 1)
    {
        return cS;
    }
    else 
        return cargo;

}
}
```

**ShipCompany Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShipCompany 
{
static ArrayList<Ship> arr;
Ship ship = new CargoShip();
Ship ship2 = new CruiseShip();

public ShipCompany()
{
    arr = new ArrayList<Ship>();
}

public static void add(Ship o)
{
    arr.add(o);
}

public String toString()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ShipDriver.getInfo() instanceof CargoShip)
        {
             return ship.toString();
        }
        else
             return ship2.toString();
    }
 }
}
```

If you need the other 3 classes I can post them like I said, but I'm pretty sure the problem might be with my toString method or my add method. I'm just not sure how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See if you can refactor this to not use any static variables

Answer (score 2):

When you call constructor of CruiseShip or CargoShip it also call super class constructor where old value of static filed `arr` lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of cS and cargo were declared as static fields. Please declare them as local variables of main method (just before do loop) and refactor the getInfo method of course

Comment: How would I refactor the getInfo method? should I create a getter and setter for the CargoShip and CruiseShip objects (can you even do this?)? I'm having trouble understanding how I would be able to create the same instances of those objects within the getInfo method. I can't really test anything right now since I don't have my laptop, but maybe you could explain it to me.

Comment: There are few ways: one way is to pass both cS and cargo as parameters to getInfo method. But indeed, you can remove the getInfo() method totally by initializing and adding the ships to the list inside your if (oneTwo==1)...else...